# Should I store user's document data on the server or on the file system?

Tags: filesystems, cloud, storage

Let's say I'm making an application that allows users to write stories in a custom file format. Should I store the resulting documents on the server like Google Docs, or on the filesystem (or cloud storage, for web apps) like Microsoft Word?

Advantages I can think of for the server are easier sharing and better organization (for example, you can sort stories by series, characters involved etc)

At the same time, the filesystem might allow better cooperation with other apps, and also have better organization (the user will be able to put stories together with documents from other apps in the same folder).

Answer (score 0):

You can store your files on a file system (cloud, whatever) and then store the meta data in a database. The meta is then searchable, sortable, etc and allows you to display in all kinds of weird and wonderful ways but also allows you to keep your database size smaller.